# Javascript: how to check if the input is correct

Tags: javascript, input

I know there is a way to make a field input and have user to type for example 'an apple' and then have javascript to check if the user typed in what I wanted which in this case is 'an apple' or if he/she typed in something else like 'a banana' and then if the answer was correct an information like 'correct' should appear and if it's not an information with 'wrong' should appear.

The question is how can I make it work?

I've searched the net for answers but it's giving me only how to check input length or something.

Can someone give me instructions or a link to a tutorial or something that would explain that, please.

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is your objective? Is it to check and see if the input is empty or not? Just an FYI what your trying to do is called input validation.

Comment: There are three parts to your problem. One is getting the value from the field. The second is comparing that value against your required field ("an apple"). The third is changing text on the screen. If you google these three separately you should have better luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try something like this

```
<input type="text" id="test">
<input type="button" value="click" onclick="z()"><span id="err"></span>

<script>
function z()
{
var a=document.getElementById("test");
if((a.value=="an apple")||(a.value=="apple"))
{
document.getElementById('err').innerHTML= 'correct';
}
else
{
document.getElementById('err').innerHTML= 'wrong';

}

}
</script>
```

Comment: I'd like to point out that the above approach is technically not the best, the unobtrusive jquery approach is more elegant. However, user3791222, because of it's simplicity you should pick this solution apart to fully understand it. It is simple examples like this that will get you a solid grasp of the basics, even if you ultimately use a less obtrusive approach.

Comment: Well that's something I needed. Thank you. But, now is there a way to show 'correct' and 'wrong' beside the button 'click' instead of making a pop-up box?
Also, can I specify two correct answers for example 'an apple' and 'apple'?